# Adding a navigation property to AbpUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship between an AbpUser (ASP.NET Boilerplate) and a class called AccountType in EF Core . I have the following code:

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
{
    public virtual int? AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountTypeId")]
    public virtual AccountType AccountTypeFk { get; set; }
}

public class AccountType : Entity
{
    [InverseProperty("AccountType")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

but when I attempt to scaffold the migration I get the following error message:

> The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Users' on type 'AccountType' is not valid. The property 'AccountType' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'User'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property>

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the name of the property with the foreign key? aka `[InverseProperty("AccountTypeFk ")]`

Comment: Yes. The error message clearly points to that.

Comment: Yes that was what was causing the problem, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Your users.AccountTypeId needs to have the virtual removed.   This will create the property in the database.   This will then allow for the foreign key to be created, and for the sql joins etc to work.

Your AccountTypeFk is okay to be virtual, However It would be more sense to remove fk from the name, as it wont be a foreign key.  it would instead be a child object.